# Exception in getting http web response in c#

Tags: c#, iis

I have the following code:

```
Stream remoteStream = null;
// Create a request to the file we are downloading
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
// Set default authentication for retrieving the file
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
// Retrieve the response from the server
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
// Ask the server for the file size and store it
Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;
```

I did setup a web server using IIS and copied the files there. Argument to the Create method is the full path to the file like http/abc.dat

I call this method again and again to download all the files in this folder. 
The line:

```
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

executes fine for for first few files and then starts giving exception 
404 protocol error. What is that I am doing wrong here. Is there anything that needs to be configured in IIS Server?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with IIS configuration... The likeliest reason is that you're trying to download files that are not there, as the error code suggests.

Comment: I have verified that the files are present. I can access the files using web browser. Is there any limitation on the number of parallel http requests.